# Subset dates in the wrong format in R

Tags: r, date, date-formatting, format-conversion

I have questionnaire data where participants have inputted their date of birth in a wide variety of formats:

```
ID <- c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107)
dob <- c("20/04/2001","29/10/2000","September 1 2012","15/11/00","20.01.1999","April 20th 1999", "04/08/01")
df <- data.frame(ID, dob)
```

Before doing any analysis, I need to be able to subset the data when it is not in the correct format (i.e. dd/mm/yr) and then correct each cell in turn manually.

I tried using:

```
df$dob <- strptime(dob, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

... to highlight which of my dates were in the correct format, but I just get NAs for the dates that are inputted incorrectly which is not helpful if I want to subsequently change them (using the ID as a reference).

Does anyone have any ideas which may be able to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(dob, c("dmy", "Bdy"))
# [1] "2001-04-20 UTC" "2000-10-29 UTC" "2012-09-01 UTC" "0000-11-15 UTC" "1999-01-20 UTC"
# [6] "1999-04-20 UTC" "0001-08-04 UTC"
```

Comment: Isn't `"0000-11-15 UTC"` a bit strange?

Comment: Interesting. A quick fix is `dob <- parse_date_time(dob, c("dmy", "Bdy")); bad.years <- year(dob) < 10; year(dob)[bad.years] <- year(dob)[bad.years] + 2000`, but that seems hackish. If anyone else has a solution to this `lubridate` feature, let me know. Otherwise, I'll dig later today out of curiosity.

Comment: First time I've seen it too.

Comment: @SlowLearner & Peyton. Possibly some hints in `select_formats`. "By default the formats with most formating tockens (%) are selected and %Y counts as 2.5 tockens (so that it can have priority over %y%m)". Then I would expect `parse_date_time(c("26/09/2013", rep("26/09/13", 5)), "dmy")` to parse at least the %y dates correctly, but it doesn't. (works: `parse_date_time(c("September 26 2013", "26/09/13"), c("dmy", "Bdy"))`)

Comment: Guys, file a bug or documentation bug on lubridate.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if I understood your question completely.

In the snippet below, dob2 will contain a date or NA based on whether dob is in the correct format. You should be able to filter for is.na(dob2) to get the incorrect data. Note that 03/04/2013 can be interpreted as 3rd March or 4th April but you seem to be assuming it to be 3rd April so I went with it.

```
ID <- c(101,102,103,104,105,106,107)
dob <- c("20/04/2001","29/10/2000","September 1 2012","15/11/00","20.01.1999","April 20th 1999", "04/08/01")
df <- data.table(ID, dob)

df[,dob2 := as.Date(dob, "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

EDIT- added output. btw, you could also have done something like `df[is.na(as.Date(dob, "%d/%m/%Y"))]`

```
    ID              dob       dob2
1: 101       20/04/2001 2001-04-20
2: 102       29/10/2000 2000-10-29
3: 103 September 1 2012       <NA>
4: 104         15/11/00 0000-11-15
5: 105       20.01.1999       <NA>
6: 106  April 20th 1999       <NA>
7: 107         04/08/01 0001-08-04
```

Comment: Thanks @Codoremifa - creating a new column works well.  I am having some trouble dealing with some years, like 00... when I do df$dob2 = as.Date(dob, "%d/%m/%Y") it makes these 0000 and not 2000, is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: Look up `strftime`, you should see the formats which are used. In your case you should be using %y and not %Y

> as.Date("01-01-00","%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "0000-01-01"
> as.Date("01-01-00","%d-%m-%y")
[1] "2000-01-01"'

Comment: Actually the dates @Codoremifa are wrong - similar to comment below indicated using another method... 20/04/2001 becomes 2020-04-20... any ideas?

Comment: @KT_1, I added the output I get. I don't understand your question, sorry.