# Parse dates in format dmy together with dmY using parse_date_time

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a vector of character representation of dates, where formats mostly are `dmY` (e.g. 27-09-2013), `dmy` (e.g. 27-09-13), and occasionally some `b` or `B` months. Thus, `parse_date_time` in package `lubridate` that "allows the user to specify several format-orders to handle heterogeneous date-time character representations" could be a very useful function for me.

However, it seems that `parse_date_time` has problem parsing `dmy` dates when they occur together with `dmY` dates. When parsing `dmy` alone, or `dmy` together with some other formats relevant to me, it works fine. This pattern was also noted in a comment to @Peyton's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028102/subset-dates-in-the-wrong-format-in-r/19028263#19028263). A quick fix was suggested, but I wish to ask if it is possible to handle it in `lubridate`.

Here I show some examples where I try to parse dates on `dmy` format together with some other formats, and specifying `orders` accordingly.

```
library(lubridate)
# version: lubridate_1.3.0

# regarding how date format is specified in 'orders':
# examples in ?parse_date_time
# parse_date_time(x, "ymd")
# parse_date_time(x, "%y%m%d")
# parse_date_time(x, "%y %m %d")
# these order strings are equivalent and parses the same way
# "Formatting orders might include arbitrary separators. These are discarded"

# dmy date only
parse_date_time(x = "27-09-13", orders = "d m y")
# [1] "2013-09-27 UTC"
# OK

# dmy & dBY
parse_date_time(c("27-09-13", "27 September 2013"), orders = c("d m y", "d B Y"))
# [1] "2013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-27 UTC"
# OK

# dmy & dbY
parse_date_time(c("27-09-13", "27 Sep 2013"), orders = c("d m y", "d b Y"))
# [1] "2013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-27 UTC"
# OK

# dmy & dmY
parse_date_time(c("27-09-13", "27-09-2013"), orders = c("d m y", "d m Y"))
# [1] "0013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-27 UTC"
# not OK

# does order of the date components matter?
parse_date_time(c("2013-09-27", "13-09-13"), orders = c("Y m d", "y m d"))
# [1] "2013-09-27 UTC" "0013-09-27 UTC"
# no
```

What about the `select_formats` argument? I am sorry to say this, but I have a hard time understand this section of the help file. And a [search for `select_formats` on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+select_formats): 0 results. Still, this section seemed relevant: "By default the formats with most formating tockens (%) are selected and %Y counts as 2.5 tockens (so that it can have priority over %y%m).". So I (desperately) tried with some additional `dmy` dates:

```
parse_date_time(c("27-09-2013", rep("27-09-13", 10)), orders = c("d m y", "d m Y"))
# not OK. Tried also 100 dmy dates.

# does order in the vector matter?
parse_date_time(c(rep("27-09-13", 10), "27-09-2013"), orders = c("d m y", "d m Y"))
# no
```

I then checked how the `guess_formats` function (also in `lubridate`) handled `dmy` together with `dmY`:

```
guess_formats(c("27-09-13", "27-09-2013"), c("dmy", "dmY"), print_matches = TRUE)
#                   dmy        dmY       
# [1,] "27-09-13"   "%d-%m-%y" ""        
# [2,] "27-09-2013" "%d-%m-%Y" "%d-%m-%Y"
# OK
```

From `?guess_formats`: `y also matches Y`. From `?parse_date_time`: `y* Year without century (00–99 or 0–99). Also matches year with century (Y format)`. So I tried:

```
guess_formats(c("27-09-13", "27-09-2013"), c("dmy"), print_matches = TRUE)
#                   dmy       
# [1,] "27-09-13"   "%d-%m-%y"
# [2,] "27-09-2013" "%d-%m-%Y"
# OK
```

Thus, `guess_format` seems to be able to deal with `dmy` together with `dmY`. But how can I tell `parse_date_time` to do the same? Thanks in advance for any comments or help.

**Update**
I posted the question on the [`lubridate` bug report](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/206), and got a rapid reply from @vitoshka: "This is a bug".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug. I am not sure So you should contact the maintainer.

Building the package source and changing one line in this internal function ( I replace `which.max` by `wich.min`):

```
.select_formats <-   function(trained){
  n_fmts <- nchar(gsub("[^%]", "", names(trained))) + grepl("%Y", names(trained))*1.5
  names(trained[ which.min(n_fmts) ]) ## replace which.max  by which.min
}
```

seems to correct the problem. Frankly I don't know why this works, but I guess it is a kind of ranking..

```
parse_date_time(c("27-09-13", "27-09-2013"), orders = c("d m y", "d m Y"))
[1] "2013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-27 UTC"

parse_date_time(c("2013-09-27", "13-09-13"), orders = c("Y m d", "y m d"))
[1] "2013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-13 UTC"
```

Comment: There seems to be something fishy happening with the `parse_date_time` function. For starters, the `select_formats=` argument never gets used, in preference to the `.select_formats` internal function. `.select_formats` also pays no attention to the frequency of occurrence of the various formats as it says it should. `%d-%m-%Y` will always win over `%d-%m-%y` as it gets an extra `1.5` weighting courtesy of the `grepl` call above. E.g.: a 1e5:1 ratio makes no difference `lubridate:::.select_formats(structure(c(100000,1), .Names = c("%d-%m-%y", "%d-%m-%Y")))`

Comment: Following from that, if you take the minimum instead of the maximum, you reverse the ranking and allow `%d-%m-%y` to win, which somehow makes things work as it should.

Comment: @thelatemail good guess! in addition, the function is recursive ( I don't know why ?) so it is hard to debug !

Comment: @agstudy, thanks a lot for your answer and for the suggested solution (+1). I will post the link to this question on [github of lubridate](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues).

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for your very helpful comments on `select_formats`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually intentional. I recall it now. It is assumed that if you have dates of the form 01-02-1845 and 01-02-03 in the same vector, then it is probably 01-02-0003 what is meant. It also avoids confusion with dates from different centuries. You cannot know if `17-05-13` refers to 20th or 21st century.

There might have also been a technical reason for this decision, but I don't remember right now.

`.select_formats` argument is the way to go:

```
my_select <-   function(trained){
  n_fmts <- nchar(gsub("[^%]", "", names(trained))) +
    grepl("%y", names(trained))*1.5
  names(trained[ which.max(n_fmts) ])
}

parse_date_time(c("27-09-13", "27-09-2013"), "dmy", select_formats = my_select)
## [1] "2013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-27 UTC"
```

`select_formats` should return formats to be applied sequentially to the input character vector. In the above example you give precedence to %y format.

I am adding this example to the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying this 'issue'. I tried your suggested code, but I didn't get the same result...`[1] "0013-09-27 UTC" "2013-09-27 UTC"`. Strange. Furthermore, I don't find your 'intentional' argument consistent with the output of `parse_date_time(c("27-09-13", "27 Sep 2013"), orders = c("d m y", "d b Y"))`. What makes '13' more '2013' in this case?

Comment: @Henrik, you should use the most recent github. As noted in other comments, select_format argument wasn't used before. You are right about the consistency reason. It is inconsistent and that indeed sucks. BTW, `orders=c("d m y", "d b Y"`, is just equivalent to orders="dmy". y order stands for both %y and %Y formats. This is documented.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to github. I understand the %y vs %Y (see my OP). Here I used a 'b' to handle 'Sep'. It is not entirely clear from `?parse_date_time` that the `select_formats` argument is not in use.

Comment: "You cannot know if 17-05-13 refers to 20th or 21st century.". Apparently `parse_date_time` 'knows' 13 is 2013 when 17-05-13 is together with dbY or dBy. That was one of the points with my question.

Comment: @Henrik, select_format was not in use, that was a bug. It was fixed in github a week or two ago.