# parse_date_time mixing up day and month

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am using `parse_date_time` on a few columns in my data which have multiple date formats. For instance, a column could have the date formats `"%d-%b-%y"` and, `"%m/%d/%Y"`.

Thus, `"06/11/2017"` (`"%m/%d/%Y"`) and `"11-Jun-17"` (`"%d-%b-%y"`) correspond to the same date: "2017-06-11" (`"%Y-%m-%d"`)

I am using `lubridate::parse_date_time` to parse the dates, where different date formats can be specified in the `orders` argument:

```
x <- c("06-11-2017", "11-Jun-17")
parse_date_time(x, orders = c("%d-%b-%y", "%m/%d/%Y"), locale = "eng")
# [1] "2017-11-06 UTC" "2017-06-11 UTC"
```

While this should spit out both dates as `"2017-06-11"`, it doesn't parse month and day correctly in the `"%m/%d/%Y"` date, checked by changing the month:

```
x <- c("05-11-2017", "11-Jun-17")
parse_date_time(x, orders = c("%d-%b-%y", "%m/%d/%Y"), locale = "eng")
# [1] "2017-11-05 UTC" "2017-06-11 UTC"
```

The `05` should be parsed as `%m`, but it is not.

My investigations of `parse_date_time` indicate there are bugs, which I think would be the case here. However, I am wondering what I can do to get the results I need?

update: here is a an example of the data i am using. by adding "exact = TRUE" it fixes my issue.

> test$Transmission.date
>    [1] "22-Feb-16" "10-Mar-16" "10-Mar-16" "10-Mar-16" "15-Jan-16" "15-Jan-16" "15-Jan-16" "15-Jan-16" "15-Jan-16" "15-Jan-16" "4/6/2016" 
>   [12] "4/6/2016"  "4/6/2016"  "4/6/2016"  "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016" "4/12/2016"
>   [23] "4/12/2016" "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016" 
>   [34] "4/4/2016"  "4/4/2016" 
>   test$Buyer.RFQ.Close.Date
>    [1] "25-Feb-16" "10-Mar-16" "10-Mar-16" "10-Mar-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "5/4/2016" 
>   [12] "5/4/2016"  "5/4/2016"  "5/4/2016"  "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016" "5/10/2016"
>   [23] "5/10/2016" "4/28/2016" "5/2/2016"  "4/28/2016" "5/2/2016"  "5/2/2016"  "5/2/2016"  "5/2/2016"  "5/2/2016"  "4/28/2016" "5/2/2016" 
>   [34] "4/28/2016" "5/2/2016" 
>   test$RFQ.close.date
>    [1] "25-Feb-16" "10-Mar-16" "10-Mar-16" "10-Mar-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "27-Jan-16" "4/22/2016"
>   [12] "4/22/2016" "4/22/2016" "4/22/2016" "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016"  "5/3/2016" 
>   [23] "5/3/2016"  ""          "4/28/2016" ""          "4/28/2016" "4/28/2016" "4/28/2016" "4/28/2016" "4/28/2016" ""          "4/28/2016"
>   [34] ""          "4/28/2016"

Comment: @alexb523 seems like a bug. I can't get it to parse both (it's either-or). I even tried `parse_date_time(x, c("%m/%d/%Y", "%d-%m-%Y"), exact=TRUE)` which seems foolproof; you could look into `select_formats` but I've never used it before

Comment: You should add `library(wherever_that_function_comes_from)`.

Comment: I think this is a bug similar to the one I reported some years ago: [Parse dates in format dmy together with dmY using parse_date_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127095/parse-dates-in-format-dmy-together-with-dmy-using-parse-date-time-in-package-lub) where some  combinations of `orders` doesn't play well. Does not work: `parse_date_time("06-11-2017", orders = c("dby", "mdY"), locale = "eng")`. Works: `parse_date_time("06-11-2017", orders = "mdY", locale = "eng")`; `parse_date_time(c("06-11-2017", "07-06-11"), orders = c("mdY", "ymd"), locale = "eng")`

Comment: @CPak i think your `exact = TRUE` does the trick!

Comment: Good! Didn't work for me (returned `NA`)...Which version of `lubridate` are you working with?

Comment: i am using 1.6.0. i will add a sample of the data i am using.

Comment: I posted an issue ([parse_date_time: orders mdy/Y don't play well with dby/Y](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/572)) is is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only two different formats, you could do it in base R with relative ease. If there can be more formats, other approach would be necessary

```
x = c("06/11/2017", "11-Jun-17")
as.Date(x, format = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%d-%b-%y")[1 + grepl(pattern = "\\D{3}", x)])
#[1] "2017-06-11" "2017-06-11"
```